# Why is replace not getting rid of my white space?

Tags: python, replace

Im trying to use replace to get rid of white space but it is not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
import re
list = ('255 +1', '282 +5', '255 + 3', '5 - 2',)

for i in list:
    # seperating the numbers in to a list
    nums = re.split(r'[+,-]\s*', i)
    #getting rid of white space in list 
    for num in nums:
        num.replace(' ', '')
    print(nums)
```

this is the output. in the first part of the lists it is not getting rid of it.

```
['255 ', '1']
['282 ', '5']
['255 ', '3']
['5 ', '2']
```

Comment: _"Why is replace not getting rid of my white space"_: Because strings are immutable. `str.replace` _does not modify the string in place_, it returns a _new_ string, so if you want to change `nums` you need to do `nums = [num.replace(' ', '') for num in nums]`

Comment: What are these numbers used for? do you need them as strings or as integer numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable objects in python, meaning their values cannot be changed. If you were to use the replace method you would have to set that to a new variable.
For example, if you wanted to use replace you would need to initialize a new String Variable and set it equal to num.replace(' ', ''), or alternatively use the strip() method with no parameters to remove trailing and leading white spaces.
If you wanted to reflect a new string without whitespaces...

```
myString = 'thisString ' #Notice the trailing whitespace 
newString = myString.strip() #Removes whitespace and stores in newString
print(newString) #This would output the string with no white space
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) we can use regex in the first step to just extract all numbers. this results in s list of 8 elements: `['255', '1', '282', '5', '255', '3', '5', '2']`

(2) we create an index by using range() with step 2

(3) we use the index from previous step to create chunks (length 2) of pairs by using a slice and append them to a list

```
import re
regex = r"(\d+)"
test_str = ("'255 +1', '282 +5', '255 + 3', '5 - 2'\n")
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str) # (1)
res = []
for ind in range(0, len(matches), 2): # (2) 
    res.append(matches[ind:ind + 2])  # (3) 
print(res)
```

output is `[['255', '1'], ['282', '5'], ['255', '3'], ['5', '2']]`